# How to run MOOG on OS X Yosemite

Tags: software, spectroscopy

By what process can a user running the latest version of OS X Yosemite execute MOOG with `$MOOG` in bash?

[Due to the removal of 32bit libraries in OS X 10.7+, the Fortran77 code for the MOOG installer cannot be compiled on OS X 10.7+](http://bathompso.com/blog/moog/). As a result, the [pip installer](https://github.com/andycasey/moog) will not work.

I have followed the instructions in the above guide, except that:

- I cannot install scisoft because the link in the page does not work
- [I have supermongo installed independently of MOOG](http://bi-jmyles.blogspot.com/2015/07/moog-vald-sm-marcs-ares-cont.html), so `$sm` works for me
- I have made my computer compile Fortran code with the [true version of gcc, not Apple gcc](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99077/how-to-set-gcc-4-8-as-default-gcc-compiler?rq=1).

Unfortunately, in addition to being unable to compile the code, the [pre-compiled binaries](https://github.com/bathompso/moog/tree/master/bin) aren't working for me right now on Yosemite 10.10.4. The error I get when I `$MOOG` is:

`open: No such file or directory
apparent state: unit 35 named /.moog/Barklem.dat
lately writing sequential formatted external IO
Abort trap: 6`

But I do have .moog in my home folder, and it has the Barklem files inside, and both the directory and files have been made readable/writable with:

`$sudo chmod +rw .moog` and `$sudo chmod +rw Bark*`

- Motivation: [Astronomers try to solve the problem independently](https://github.com/andycasey/moog/issues/6)
- Justification: AstronomySE topics include: "Setting up, using and maintaining your astronomy related equipment"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to execute [the compiled binaries](https://github.com/bathompso/moog/tree/master/bin), all libraries on which the executable depends must be in the correct location. In particular, the error specified in the question is due to the fact that my .moog folder was in ~/, my user home folder, rather than /, the root of my hard drive, as explained [here](https://github.com/andycasey/moog/issues/6#issuecomment-118881869).

To solve the problem:

`cd`

`mv .moog /.moog`

See [this link](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/11433/how-to-specify-sm-libraries-for-moog/11434#11434) for answer on how to get MOOG to find SM libraries for plotting.