# How to specify SM libraries for MOOG

Tags: spectroscopy, software

I am running MOOG on OS X Yosemite and with `$MOOG` running the abfind driver I can force fit elemental abundances with an appropriate input line list and model atmosphere. MOOG crashes, however, when I try to use it to generate plots, even though I know I have SuperMONGO (sm) installed on my computer because `$sm` works fine. In particular, MOOG will crash with the following errors:

```
*******************************************************************************
                  MOOG IS CONTROLLED BY DRIVER abfind                      
*******************************************************************************

wav. correl.:  slope =  -7.791E-07  intercept =   7.505  corr. coeff. =  -0.122
Fonts file not found
File graphcap is not defined
Can't get graphcap entry for nodevice
No such device nodevice
File graphcap is not defined
Can't get graphcap entry for x11
No such device x11 -bg black -title MOOGplot -geom 700x800+650+000
```

How can I get MOOG to find these libraries?

Comment: Please consider this meta post with an answer (5 net upvotes) justifying a question like this : http://meta.astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/299/are-questions-about-installing-astronomy-related-python-packages-on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MOOG will search for the libraries through a .sm file. To solve this error, download an example sm file like [this one](https://gist.github.com/jtmyles/4085763ec32cdfbbf843), and specify where your libraries are in this file. Then use `mv .sm ~/.sm` to place this in your home folder, then MOOG should be able to create plots with SM.